# How can I see Chinese characters in the Windows Subsystem for Linux terminal?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, chinese

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 via Windows Subsystem for Linux using [these official instructions](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows).

I'm trying to get the Ubuntu terminal to show Chinese characters, like this:

```
ronald@LAPTOP-FLRIMKMQ:~$ 你你
```

However, that ends up looking like this:

[image: ronald@LAPTOP-FLRIMKMQ:~$ ⍰ ⍰]

Or, in text form:

```
ronald@LAPTOP-FLRIMKMQ:~$ ⍰ ⍰
```

How can I get it to show Chinese characters correctly?

Comment: Read e.g. [Change font for non-legacy command prompt in Windows 10 with non-ASCII charset …](https://superuser.com/q/1202072/376602). For instance, `NSimSun` or `MS Gothic` font works for me quite well. (FYI, `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont"` in `cmd` shows `*新宋体` and `*ＭＳ ゴシック`, respectively). Another link https://superuser.com/q/5035/376602

Comment: Thank you so much. Recently, I found I can just change the font by right click the cmd and change to NSimSun or MS Gothic, then I can see the Chinese.